# How to use DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain() in java code to fetch credentials from instance profile and allow access to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sts

I am working on a requirement where i want to connect to s3 bucket using springboot application.
When i am connecting through my local environment i am using seeting **loadCredentials(true)** which uses Amazon STS which fetches the temperoriy credentials using a role and allow access to s3 bucket.

When i am deploying to the qa/prd envirment i am setting **loadCredentials(false)** which uses DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain() class to fetch the credential from aws instance profile(role is assigned to ec2 instance) and allow access to s3 bucket. My code is

```
 @Configuration
   public class AmazonS3Config
   { 
static String clientRegion = "ap-south-1";
static String roleARN = "arn:aws:iam::*************:role/awss3acess";
static String roleSessionName = "bucket_storage_audit";
String bucketName = "testbucket";

//Depending on environment is set to true(for local environment) or false(for qa and prd environment)
private static AWSCredentialsProvider loadCredentials(boolean isLocal) {
    final AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
    if (isLocal) {
        AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                .withRegion(clientRegion)
                .build();

        AssumeRoleRequest assumeRoleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest().withDurationSeconds(3600)
                .withRoleArn(roleARN)
                .withRoleSessionName(roleSessionName);

        AssumeRoleResult assumeRoleResult = stsClient.assumeRole(assumeRoleRequest);
        Credentials creds = assumeRoleResult.getCredentials();

        credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                new BasicSessionCredentials(creds.getAccessKeyId(),
                        creds.getSecretAccessKey(),
                        creds.getSessionToken())
        );
    } else {
        
        System.out.println("inside default");
        credentialsProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
    }

    return credentialsProvider;
}
```

// Amazon s3client Bean return an instance of s3client
.    @Bean
public AmazonS3 s3client() {

```
  AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
              .withRegion(Regions.fromName(clientRegion))
                          .withCredentials(loadCredentials(false))
                          .build();
  
  return s3Client;
}
}
```

My question since the credentials  of instance profile rotate after every 12 hours my application will fail after 12 hours.
What will i do to avoid this from happening in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `ProfileCredentialsProvider` instead of `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` as there is no need in your case to chain the credsproviders.

and about your question, `AWSCredentialsProvider`  has `refresh()` method that will reread the config file.when an Authentication exception Occurs while using S3Client you can retry again and call `refresh()` first.

Comment: Hi @stacker
my understanding is ProfileCredentialsProvider will look for .aws file and will fetch the credentials and then allow access to s3. But in prd i donot want to save credentials in .aws file. so i am using DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain to fetch the credentials from instance profile.

Also Can you please give me example of how to refresh the aws credentials . what do i change in the code?